# How can I use mpu6050 and arduino uno to control cube so the cube will move with mouse position?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arduino, mpu6050

When I first tried the arduino code with my mpu6050, the serial monitor showed the readings. However, when I tried to connect it with unity, the readings cannot be showed or used in unity. I was stuck at this problem. I was trying to make the cube that i created in unity to move with the mouseposition then replaced by the mpu 6050.

Arduino code

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <I2Cdev.h>
#include <MPU6050.h>

MPU6050 mpu;
int16_t ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz;
int vx, vy;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  mpu.initialize();
  //if (!mpu.testConnection()) { while (1); }
}

void loop() {
 mpu.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);

 vx = ((gx+300)/150)-1;  // "+300" because the x axis of gyroscope give 
 values about -350 while it's not moving. Change this value if you get 
 something different using the TEST code, chacking if there are values far 
 from zero.
 vy = -(gz-100)/150; // same here about "-100"

 String output = String(gx) + ";" + String(gz) + ";" + String(vx) + ";" + 
 String(vy);

 Serial.println(output);
 Serial.flush();

 delay(10);
 }
```

Unity code

```
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour {

SerialPort stream = new SerialPort("COM4", 115200);
public Camera cam;
public float mousex;
public float mousey;
public GameObject target; // is the gameobject to
public float acc_normalizer_factor = 0.00025f;
public float gyro_normalizer_factor = 1.0f / 32768.0f;   // 32768 is max 
value captured during test on imu

//float curr_angle_x = 0;
//float curr_angle_y = 0;
//float curr_angle_z = 0;

float curr_offset_x = 0;
float curr_offset_y = -2;



void Start()
{

    stream.Open();


    cam = Camera.main;


}

void Update()
{
    string dataString = "null received";
    dataString = stream.ReadLine();

    char splitChar = ';';
    string[] dataRaw = dataString.Split(splitChar);

    float vx = int.Parse(dataRaw[2]);
    float vy = int.Parse(dataRaw[3]);

    curr_offset_x += (vx * acc_normalizer_factor);
    curr_offset_y += (vy * acc_normalizer_factor);
    //get mouse possition
    mousex = (curr_offset_x);
    mousey = (curr_offset_y);
    //adapt it to screen
    // 5 in z to be in the front of the camera, but up to you, just 
avoid 0
    Vector3 mouseposition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousex, 
mousey, 5));
     //make your gameobject fallow your input
    target.transform.position = mouseposition;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your device. Is the data being sent by your device and received by machine the mpu is connected to?
Also you can try to `Debug.Log(dataString)` in Unity right after `dataString = stream.ReadLine();` in your code (it makes sense only if data from mpu is receiving by machine your device is connected to).

Comment: I had tried your method and I can get the Reading from mpu but the Reading always constant which is 0; 0; 2; 0. Anyone can help?

Comment: @user11940781,  it seems like Unity can read data from Serial port correctly. The problem is in the firmware or with mpu. Anyway, you can do some additional tests to prove it. Use `String output = "Test"` (for example) and check it using `Debug.Log()` in Unity.